# Azure App Service Environment - Why can't I select an existing Subnet?

Tags: azure, web-applications, cloud, subnet, vnet

I am building an App Service Environment but in the wizard I need to create a new subnet within my vNET. Why can't I select the currect subnet?

I now need to do the following reasonless steps:

1. Create Virtual Network with Subnet
2. Remove Subnet from Virtual Network
3. Create App Service Environment
4. Create Subnet during App Service Environment wizard

Is it possible to select an existing subnet during the creation of an ASE?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the requirements to use an existing subnet, is that it is empty:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-network-configuration-expressroute#example-udr-configuration-for-an-app-service-environment

> you will need to delete the virtual machine because **the subnet needs
>   to be "empty" at the time the App Service Environment is created**

Possible that you are not able to select an existing subnet because you've deployed something into that subnet.

Comment: Well mine was empty but I get the point. Guess the "Existing Subnets" list is just for reference.

Comment: For others that come along, you can deploy into an existing subnet using ARM templates or the CLI - but just not through the Portal UI.